# How does ejabberd handle really high number of requests

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

How does ejabberd handle really high number of requests. For eg.

- I have only 1 instance running.

**I am assuming:**

- Lets take mod_offline.erl for example
- This module gets started by ejabberd_admin when server is started
- Using gen_server callbacks.

-- Is there only a single instance of this module running or are there multiple instances of the module running at the same time
-- If multiple then how many such instances?

I was also curious what needs to be done to write a custom module to be able to handle high number of requests simultaneously.

Could you please provide some pointers?

I am very new to erlang and ejabberd. Please help me understand how does ejabberd take care of high requests.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical Erlang way of doing things is to spawn a process per independent task (or set of tasks).

Process spawning is cheap and the scheduling is both extremely lightweight and generally handled for you automatically -- so this is the easy way of modeling a massively concurrent problem in Erlang (and chat messaging is a a perfect example of such a problem).

So its not "instances of a module" it is "lots of processes executing code from a module" -- sort of (to be specific, one process will typical execute code from several modules in its lifetime, and this is inherent to any sort of callback-based OTP behavior).

To get a better grip on this sort of thing I recommend writing a few Erlang program from scratch yourself that deal with concurrent user input. Network programming in Erlang is easy. Writing a few servers yourself from scratch will give you a lot of insight into why OTP behaviors work the way they do.

I'm working on an intermediate instructional that starts out with a discussion about architecture that may shed some light on this. The first (deliberately unidiomatic and non-OTP) iteration of the code illustrates a lot of the basic ideas behind how network requests are handled, and how processes are spawned to model various concurrent elements of a system. It is still a work in progress, but what exists so far should illustrate some of the things you have questions about: [The ErlMUD Commentary](http://zxq9.com/erlmud/).

Comment: so for example for each offline_message to be handled, ejabberd will spawn a erlang process?

Comment: @user2384694 offline_message is probably put into a queue (or table that works as a queue) which is popped based on some criteria (like the intended user coming online). But you'd have to check the code to be sure; ejabberd is notorious for its poor documentation -- the place to figure it out would probably be RabbitMQ (it was originally based on ejabberd, but better documented and a bit easier to understand IMO). In any case, messages are just messages (not processes), but user connection and other elements of the system (channels, etc) are processes.